# How does base_convert () create a random character string in php?

Tags: php, math

I am learning php myself with short exercises and I came through this small excercise to generate random 11 character string

```
public function Random_string()
 {
        $number = rand(10e12, 10e16);
        echo base_convert($number, 10, 36);
   //Sample output=9n4jfyh18v9
 }
```

I thought the function generated string itself but when i use following values then it does not generate any string.

```
<?php
$number = "0977567";
echo base_convert($number,8,10);
//output=32631
?>
```

As far as i know `rand()` function generates random numbers while `base_convert()` function converts a number from one number base to another. In this process how does a string gets generated? It was very hard for me to understand this. It would be very nice if some could shed light on it. Thank you.

**P.S. The first function shows error in PHP 7 but it completely works in PHP 5**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, `rand(int $min, int $max)` generates a random **integer number** between `$min` and `$max`, [see documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php).

And `base_convert(string $num, int $from_base, int $to_base)` converts `$num` from `$from_base` to `$to_base`, but `$num` here is a **string**, because hexadecimal and other numbers above base 10 **can contain characters as well**, not only numbers, [see documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base-convert.php). That's also the reason why this functions returns a string, even if in some cases it won't actually contain any letters.

PHP also converts string to number if needed, for example next code will output `124` as `int`:

```
$a = "123";
var_dump($a+1);
```

In your first example, even if `$number` is an integer, PHP does the favour for you that it converts it into string, when you invoke `base_convert` from base 10 to 36.

In your second example, there is a problem, because the input `$number="0977567"` contains digit `9`, and you want to convert it from base 8 to 10. But digit `9` does not exist in a base 8 number, only digits from `0` to `7`. In this case PHP ignores invalid character `9`, and converts only `077567` from base 8 to base 10, which happens to be `32631`.

Please always check PHP warnings to catch issues like this. While learning and testing it is a good idea to set `error_reporting(E_ALL);` so you will get every message. Check [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php).